# Bar Chart Update D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using this sample: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

My update code is:

```
function updateData() {

    d3.tsv("new.tsv", type, function (error, data) {

        console.log(data);

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.name; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);


        // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
        var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

        // Make the changes
        var sel = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);
        //sel.exit().remove();
        //sel.enter().append("rect");


        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);

    });
}
```

But I'm getting an error at

```
var sel = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data)
```

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

What's the problem and how can I dynamically update the tsv data from the bar chart with animation?

Comment: You cannot make selection on a transition. You probably want something like `var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");`

Comment: Why then the x and y axis are working?

Comment: Do you actually see the axes? The code for this should never be run as you have an error before.

Comment: if I commit the error line the axes are updating (transforming) already very well. So I just need to update the bars but dont know how

Comment: Well let me make my earlier statement more precise: it's the *data binding* that's the problem. Technically, you can make selections from transitions, but these behave different from the selections you make on selections. It's the `.data()` that's the problem.

Comment: Okay but then how I can update the data optionally with transition?

Comment: Add `.transition()` just before setting the new attributes/styles.